# How to get location pathname with React Router v5 and Hooks in React v16.13.1?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I have some issue with React Router `useLocation` and how to get the current pathname.

Here is what I'm doing :

```
    import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link} from "react-router-dom";
    import {useHistory, useLocation} from 'react-router-dom'
        
    function Home(props) {
        const [isHome, setIsHome] = useState(true);
        const [isContents, setIsContents] = useState(false);
        const [isUserProfile, setIsUserProfile] = useState(false);
        let location = useLocation();
        let history = useHistory();
    
        console.log(location)
        console.log(history)
    
        function getCurrentLocation() {
    
        }
    
        function logout() {
            const logger = fetch('/users/logout');
            logger.then(logout => {
                if (logout.ok) {
                    props.logout()
                } else {
                    console.log('error', logout);
                }
            })
        }
 
    
        return (
            <Router>
                <div className={'container-fluid h-100'}>
                    <div className={'row'}>
                        <ul className={"nav nav-tabs"}>
                            <li className={"nav-item"}>
                                <Link to={'/home'}>1</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className={"nav-item"}>
                                <Link to={'/contents'}>2</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className={"nav-item"}>
                                <Link to={'/user'}>3</Link>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path={'/home'}>1</Route>
                        <Route path={'/contents'}>2</Route>
                        <Route path={'/user'}>3</Route>
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </Router>
        )
    };
    
    export default Home
```

I want to get the currentLocationPathName in order to apply some custom style.
When I make a `console.log(location)` this is what I get back:

```
function useLocation() {
 if (true) {
    !(typeof useContext === "function") ?  true ? Object(tiny_invariant__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__["default"])(false, "You must use React >= 16.8 in order to use useLocation()") : undefined : void 0;
  }

  return useContext(context).location;
}
```

Here a screenshot for more informations:

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C585Y.png)

I want to better understand how to use these Hooks.

Thank you for your time.

Edit:

Thank you to @Dance2die for his answer and specially this recommendation:

> And also make sure Home is used under a tree of a router (e.g.) BrowserRouter) (child, grandchild, etc)

I did not put `Home` under `<Router></Router>` tree...

Now it's working good and I can get access to the `location.pathname`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`useHistory` and `useLocation` are functions so you need to invoke them.

Instead of

```js
let location = useLocation;
let history = useHistory
```

Invoke the hook functions.

```js
                          
let location = useLocation()
                        
let history = useHistory()
```

And also make sure `Home` is used under a tree of a router (e.g.) `BrowserRouter`) (child, grandchild, etc)

---

**Old answer before the OP's edit.**

Hooks were added in v16.8.0.
https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#react-2

So the message tells you that you can't use `useLocation` with your version of React, v16.3.1.

To fix the issue, you need to upgrade React to at least v16.8.0 (preferably the latest, to prepare for React Router v6 to be released hopefully early or mid this year).

Comment: Hello @dance2die thank your for your time but I made a mistake... I have the latest version of Reactjs v16.13.1 I've edited my question title. Even if have the latest version why I get this error message? It's something I'm doing wrong in my code?

Comment: Thank You @dance2die , but I still have the same error message... I've updated my post.

Comment: Ok @dance2die ! thank you for your time and answer. I put Home under a Router tree as you recommended and it's working.